# Unable to execute code inside didReceiveRemoteNotification fetchCompletionHandler

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using silent push notification and manage to invoke the `didReceiveRemoteNotification` when the push notification arrives at the device. However I am not able to execute my code when the delegate is executed. Based on the code below, I am able to observe the `NSLog` of "Print progress 1", but I am not able to see "Print progress 2".

Can someone advise whether the usage below is inaccurate? I am trying to prolong the period of the task in background. I tried removing `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHeader` but the code will not execute as well.

```
-(void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result)) handler {
    NSLog(@"Print progress 1");

    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask;
    bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^ {

        ///..... Background thread codes.... 

        NSLog(@"Print progress 2");

        [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        handler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check if your backgrounding takes to much time, maybe the app is killed before reaching the point of logging `"Print Progress 2"`:

> Apps running background tasks have a **finite amount of time** in which to
>   run them. (You can find out how much time is available using the
>   `backgroundTimeRemaining` property.) If you do not call
>   `endBackgroundTask:` for each task before time expires, **the system kills
>   the app.**

and / or should debug correctly and be sure your code is executed:

> If you are having trouble debugging your background task code, you
>   might try using the `beginBackgroundTaskWithName:expirationHandler:`
>   method instead of this one. That method provides the same behavior as
>   this one but lets you specify a **debugger-visible** name for your task.